# kivy detect clicks on widgets within screen

Tags: python, kivy

I have a screen with multiple widgets within it. I need to detect if the user clicked the label - 'home'

Whenever I click the screen the on_touch_down and on_touch_up is triggered. how can I determine the label that I clicked..

```
class WordScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        label_text = kwargs['label_text']
        del kwargs['label_text']
        super(WordScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        main_layout = BoxLayout(id='test', orientation='vertical')
        navigation_layout = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal',
                                      size_hint_y=.1)
        navigation_layout.add_widget(Label(text='home'))
        navigation_layout.add_widget(Label(text='audio'))
        navigation_layout.add_widget(Label(text='favorite'))
        text_layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        text_layout.add_widget(Label(id='sight_text', text=label_text))
        main_layout.add_widget(navigation_layout)
        main_layout.add_widget(text_layout)

        self.add_widget(main_layout)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        self.initial = touch.x

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        print('on_touch_up - ', touch.x)

        print(self.collide_point(*touch.pos))
        print(touch.button)
        s = None
        try:
            s = self.manager.get_screen('settings')
        except ScreenManagerException:
            pass
        print('screen - ', s)
        if s is not None:
            self.manager.clear_widgets([s])
        print('screen removed')
        if touch.x < self.initial:
            self.manager.transition = SlideTransition(direction="right")
            self.manager.current = self.manager.next()
        elif touch.x > self.initial:

            self.manager.transition = SlideTransition(direction="right")
            self.manager.current = self.manager.previous()
```

Comment: how about `label.bind('press', function)` or something similar ? And in function maybe it will get `event.widget` or something similar.

Comment: @furas That does not work, it triggers only the on_touch_down event

Comment: You can define an `ImageButton` as shown [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.behaviors.button.html#example), and use that for the 'home' `Label`. Then assign your desired code to the `on_press` or `on_release`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [link](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.behaviors.button.html#example) from John Anderson comment I created clickable Label.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior


class MyLabel(ButtonBehavior, Label):

    def on_press(self):
        print("press:", self.text)

    def on_release(self):
        print("release:", self.text)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLabel(text="Hello")


MyApp().run()
```

---

But problem can be that `on_touch_down` and `on_touch_up` may block other events and then even standard `Button` will not work. You may have to check `on_touch_down` and `on_touch_up` only in widget which doesn't need `on_press`, `on_release`

Probably it could be resolved using only `on_touch_move` without `on_touch_down`, `on_touch_up`

---

**EDIT:**

Minimal working code.

It uses clickable Label and `on_touch_move` without `on_touch_down`, `on_touch_up` to slide screen.

BTW: I use `if touch.dx < -3:` instead of `if touch.dx < 0:` to skip very small moves. I tested it only with mouse but for findgers it may need different value.

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from functools import partial

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, SlideTransition

from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior


class MyLabel(ButtonBehavior, Label):

    def on_press(self):
        print("pressed:", self.text)

    def on_release(self):
        print("release:", self.text)


class WordScreen(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        label_text = kwargs['label_text']
        del kwargs['label_text']

        super(WordScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        main_layout = BoxLayout(id='test', orientation='vertical')
        navigation_layout = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal',
                                      size_hint_y=.1)

        navigation_layout.add_widget(MyLabel(text='home'))
        navigation_layout.add_widget(MyLabel(text='audio'))
        navigation_layout.add_widget(MyLabel(text='favorite'))

        text_layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        #text_layout.add_widget(Label(id='sight_text', text=label_text))
        text_layout.add_widget(Label(id='sight_text', text=self.name))

        main_layout.add_widget(navigation_layout)
        main_layout.add_widget(text_layout)

        self.add_widget(main_layout)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        #print('touch variable:\n', "\n".join(dir(touch)))
        print('touch.dx:', touch.dx)
        print('touch.dsx:', touch.dsx)
        #print('touch.distance:', touch.distance)
        #print('touch.move:', touch.move)

        if touch.dx < -3:   # using `touch.dx < 0` it slides even on very small moves
            self.manager.transition = SlideTransition(direction="right")
            self.manager.current = self.manager.next()
        elif touch.dx > 3:  # using `touch.dx > 0` it slides even on very small moves
            self.manager.transition = SlideTransition(direction="right")
            self.manager.current = self.manager.previous()

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(WordScreen(name='menu', label_text="Example"))
sm.add_widget(WordScreen(name='settings', label_text="Example"))

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

---

**EDIT:**

Problem with `on_touch_down`, `on_touch_up` which block `on_press`, `on_release` can be resolved using `super()` to execute original code `on_touch_down`, `on_touch_up`

```
def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    # ... code ...
    return super(WordScreen, self).on_touch_down(touch)

def on_touch_up(self, touch):
    # ... code ...
    return super(WordScreen, self).on_touch_up(touch)
```

Based on example in documentation: [Events - Dispatching a Property event](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/events.html#dispatching-a-property-event)